# paramiko-python exec_command() cannot work on channel type tuple :(

Tags: python, paramiko

## Test Function

```
def GetTestFile():
    sshConn = paramiko.SSHClient()
    sshConn.load_system_host_keys()
    sshConn.connect(host, port, usrnm, pwrd)
    (connin, out, err) = sshObj.exec_command("cat test.txt")
    print out.readlines()
    lines = []
    for i in out.readlines():
        lines = lines.append(i)
        print lines
    print "Lines: ", lines
    sshConn.close()
```

As you know this performs a simple cat on the remote server. I want to transfer the contents of the out in to lines but when it outputs as [] (I checked the for loop doesn't seem to be executed for some odd reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `list.append` method does not return the list, it is an in-place append. You want

```
for i in out.readlines():
    lines.append(i)
    print lines
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't seem to get into the for loop.

Comment: I found the problem. The `out` object can only be iterated once then it loses it's list. Hence the for loop does not work.

Comment: I would then suggest not doing `print out.readlines()` there, since you do a lot of printing of those lines just afterwards anyway.